# Dashboard indicator comes up with key exclamation sign

Tags: toyota, indicators, yaris, vitz

Recently, a indicator light started to come up in my Toyota Vitz (yaris) 2007. Following is the indicator sign.

[image]

This indicator comes up in an irregular pattern. Most of the time, the indicator comes up when I open a door and goes away when I close the door. The key does not necessarily be inserted to the keyhole for this indicator to come up. Also, sometimes when this comes up, it blinks randomly.

My key fob battery is ok. I replaced it recently and lock/unlock works without a problem.

What could be the issue here?

Couple of years ago, I replaced the engine wire harness of the vehicle. In the new harness, some wires were cut off at the fuse box, so mechanic had to solder these wires to the old wire harness. Can this be due to a problem with the soldering?

Comment: What does your vehicle manual say about this dashboard indicator?

Comment: @MadMarky My manual doesn't say anything about this indicator. When I searched for the indicator in the internet, it looks like this indicator indicates that the key is not in the vehicle. But, I am not sure about it. Anyway, my vehicle doesn't need to detect whether key is in the vehicle or not because the car doesn't have a start button.